# How quickly climate zones are shifting due to climate change!

Tags: climate-change, climate, climate-models

Hi I was wondering how fast the climate zones (according to W. Köppen) have shifted in the last 22 years. It is well known that the zones shift about 100-200 km to the north or south for each degree Celsius increase in air temperature! Are there any current studies that prove this since the turn of the millennium, or is this a period that is too short to be representative?

Comment: Since you mentioned, Koppen, I assume you're familiar with http://koeppen-geiger.vu-wien.ac.at/ ?

Comment: Looks like a solid answer to me.  Koppen climate zones are a general topic, the plots you show are specialized things I certainly haven't come across, and look to answer the question well (particularly with the concurrent references)