# Is there a georeferenced map/GIS resource for the IPCC definitions of climate zone available?

Tags: climate-data

I hope to find a GIS resource for the IPCC definitions of climate zones, e.g.
*"Temperate, cold climate: Areas where mean annual temperature (MAT) is between 0 – 10 C, and the ratio of mean annual precipitation to potential evapotranspiration is less than or equal to 1"*. With the necessary data it is possible to derive these myself, but unfortunately I don't have the climate and elevation files available and was hoping that such a map is already published.

Comment: There are similar questions (and answers) for the Köppen-Geiger classification at both GIS and Open Data stack exchanges: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/16113 You could try there.

Comment: And this on on here https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/23929/how-quickly-climate-zones-are-shifting-due-to-climate-change, where there's a possibly useful link in the comments